# How to write nested fsm in Chisel like SpinalHDL does?

Tags: chisel, spinalhdl

I've found that SpinalHDL has [some powerful and elegant ways](https://spinalhdl.github.io/SpinalDoc-RTD/master/SpinalHDL/Libraries/fsm.html) to describe a rather complicated fsm. I wonder if it's possible to construct a FSM lib (like SpinalHDL has done) in Chisel?
p.s. I'm not very familiar with scala.‍️

Answer (score 0):

Chisel does not currently have a FSM library. We normally write state machines explicitly using a `ChiselEnum` for the state register.
If you like the API that Spinal has, but need/want to use Chisel, it should not be to hard to make a similar API on top of Chisel. Chisel is designed to allow you to add your own favorite abstractions by adding your own Scala library code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).